# Wordpress Conditional Check in The Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, date, loops, conditional-statements

So I'm trying to add a conditional statement for a set of post information appearing in the sidebar as an "Event" calendar.

Basically it shows the date of the post, the post title, and a small excerpt with a link to the post.

I had that all working fine, but I now need it to do some things differently.

Right now I need it to:

1) Check whether or not a post's date is Today's Date.

2) If a post is today's date then do the following: Show the post if it has the category 'Entries', otherwise if it doesn't and there are no posts today with the category 'Entries' then show any other post that's today.

I will also want to do something where a post only show's on certain days of the week. Not sure how I could build in that function and then check for that as well.

Here is the code I have so far that doesn't work:

```
<?php

  $today = getdate();

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    // 'day' => $today['mday']
  );


  // The Query
  $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

  foreach($my_posts as $posts) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

  <?php if( $post->is_category=='Entries' ) : ?>
          <li>
             <p class="date">
               <a href=""><span class="month"></span></a> 
               <a href=""><span class="day"></span></a>
             </p>
             <p class="info">
               <a href=""><?php the_title(); ?><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a><br>
              </p>      
             <div class="clear"></div>
           </li>';

   <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I looked at some other examples through the Wordpress forums that didn't work once I checked for a category name.

Above I'm just checking to see if it will show anything at all just checking for a category but it's not. I'm looking at the codex, but I think I am just not understanding it right.

And this is another question, but apart of this one. Is there a way to set a date range for a post, meaning, this post will be up between June 1st and June 10th and who's post date will show up as today.

For example (and I might be losing some of your already) I setup an event that lasts from June 1 to June 5th. On the calendar it shows up as whatever day it's currently on.

Comment: I want to add this which I just explained to a friend that I hope can explain this a bit better:

http://pastie.org/private/ddnppzivg5bjomho0afa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check if post was published today:**

```
$postDate = strtotime( $post->post_date );
$todaysDate = time();
if($postDate == $todaysDate){
//code block
}
```

**To check if post belongs to a particular category:**

```
if ( in_category( 'Entries' )) {
//code block
}
```

See [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

**To list the posts published today:**

```
$day = date('j');
query_posts( "day=$day&order=ASC" );
```

See [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts)

I think it should be easy now. Good luck!

Comment: I wound up using the events calendar plugin as a solution. Still running into just one last issue, but this did help for my other problem before the plugin use.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `is_category` correctly. [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Try changing `$post->is_category=='Entries'` to `$post->is_category('Entries')`

Comment: He probably wants in_category(). See my answer :)